# Solace Client BindFailedError Selector Invalid: exceeds 1023 bytes

Tags: solace

I have .Net client that connects and works fine for a while and then disconnects and fails to reconnect because of an Invalid Selector error. There is no selector being passed so I don't know what the issue is.

See log below:

```
2019-01-28T19:47:56.8258311Z SolaceConsumer FlowEvent ParentSessionDown Session for Flow disconnected
2019-01-28T19:47:56.8264139Z SolaceConsumer SessionEvent Reconnecting solClientOS.c:5745                   (7f50727bb700) Peer closed socket, fd 92, cannot read
2019-01-28T19:47:57.1187156Z SolaceConsumer SessionEvent Reconnected host 'serverSolace:55003', hostname 'serverSolace:55003' IP 54.245 (host 1 of 1) (host connection attempt 1 of 1) (total reconnection attempt 1 of -1)
2019-01-28T19:47:57.1204652Z SolaceConsumer solClientFlow.c:4286                 (7f50727bb700) Selector Invalid: exceeds 1023 bytes
2019-01-28T19:47:57.1205778Z SolaceConsumer FlowEvent BindFailedError Selector Invalid: exceeds 1023 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing bug in Solace version 10.3.0.0
Solace has fixed this issue in their upper version 10.3.2.0, you can use the higher version to solve this issue.

Comment: I switched to 10.4 and still have the issue.